# How to get last edit point of editing a UITextView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I am trying to get the last editing point of a UITextView box.

I have tried getting the value textView.selectedRange.location,but it always comes out as 2147483647 (which is -1).

When should I read this value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the `selectedRange` in [the `-textViewShouldEndEditing:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewShouldEndEditing:) of your delegate, and then use this saved value.

Comment: Found my mistake. Need to do it just before resignFirstResponder